# Jquery change css class from variable

Tags: html, jquery, css

For my site, I code a button allowing to change the css of a class present in a div card. My button is located in the card-footer. Having several cards, I can't / don't think to retrieve the element with an id (as there will be X times the same ID)

In order to circumvent this system, I therefore use a parentElement which goes up to the div card

```
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-body">
  <p class="change">Change one</p>
  <p class="change">Change two</p>
  <p class="change">Change three</p>
 </div>
 <div class="card-footer">
   <i id="updateData">change</i>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
jQuery($ => {
  $('#updateData').click(e => {
    var element = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    $('.change').css('display','none');
  });
});
```

I would like to indicate that only the class "changes" present in my element variable and not all the classes in the page.

I don't know how to add a variable to my ".css" command, do you know how ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all since you will have multiple elements with same id that means that you should not use ID and use class instead. **Id is meant to be unique**. So yours `id="updateData"` should become `class="updateData"`. Now you can grab all of those buttons and assign event to all of them instead of just first like you were by using id selector.

```
 $('.updateData').click(e=> {});
```

Next in order to be able to use clicked element in jQuery way convert from arrow function to regular anonymous function since arrow function overrides `this` keyword. And now you can use jQuery to hide like

```
 $('.updateData').click(function() {
    element = $(this).parent().parent();
    element.hide();
  });
```

If you want more precise selection to hide only `.change` elements use

```
  $('.updateData').click(function() {
    element = $(this).parent().parent();
    element.find(".change").hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not bad, but more efficient, when you have multiple click targets, is delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".updateData", function() { ... });
```

Also .hide() is convenient, but rather then "change the css of a class" add a class "hidden" or something! In best case the class further describes what the element is. CSS is just on top.